# Why does TalkBack ignore currency values equal to zero?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Does anyone know why TalkBack reads the text "Balance: $0.00" as simply "Balance"? It seems to ignore values equivalent to zero. I would expect it to be read as "Balance: zero dollars."

```
view.announceForAccessibility("Total: $0.00"); // Reads "Total"
view.announceForAccessibility("Total: $0"); // Reads "Total"
view.announceForAccessibility("Total: 0"); // Reads "Total: Zero"
```

I [filed a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52027) on the Android project, but was wondering if anyone here had some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the text-to-speech engine, and should be fixed in later versions of the engine.

To work around it, you can either use a different TTS engine (ex. SVOX Classic) or specify the announcement as "Total: zero dollars" when you know the value is zero.

Comment: Thanks @alanv I'm actually handling it by converting "$0.00" to "zero dollars" just as you suggest. Is there a bug report somewhere that I can track the progress of the fix? I wasn't sure exactly where to file accessibility bugs.